# Django: a custom view inside /static/ directory

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-staticfiles

Community,

I am using Django 1.7. Due to specific nature of the project, I have complicated needs for handling static files. In other words, I need `/static/` to be served on development just as usual, but `/static/blueprints/` subdirectory should be served by a custom view.

It seems anyway that static serving view has priority above everything in `urls.py`. The following just does not work:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^static/blueprints/(?P<blueprint>[\w-]+)/(?P<path>.+)', 'my_view_name'),
    ...
)
```

The view never gets fired when accessing an appropriate URL. But changing `static/blueprints` to, say, `my_static/blueprints` makes this path to work, so the view actually does work.

Of course, I need that only on development; on production, a script will be used to form the necessary directory structure served by Nginx. So solutions:

1. Avoid using `debug=True` on devserver. But Django's debugger is very useful.
2. Avoid using `django.contrib.staticfiles`. Not pleasing too, I'd like to use the `collectstaic` command.
3. Use just `/blueprints/` path instead of `/static/blueprints/`, which is a solution, but just against aesthetics.

Is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: `my_view_name`? or how you suppose view makes this path to work? https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/static.py#L21

Comment: Well, `my_view_name` is actually `myapp.views.blueprint_view`, which is my own view. And it actually employs the view you linked to, just adds some custom logic.

Comment: So I don't know what that view actually does, but while using `serve` you must provide the ``document_root`` param and where the `$` in the end of your pattern? `url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),`

Comment: I understand that. I do not use `serve` in here; if I would, that would not be a problem, I'd just added an item to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. I have my own view which has its own logic of serving static files from multiple directories. And it does its job, as I have noted in the question. The problem is that this view URL is overwritten by Django's own static serving logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `./manage.py runserver` on your dev server, right? Then you can go this way: `./manage.py runserver --nostatic`, and in urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^static/blueprints/(?P<blueprint>[\w-]+)/(?P<path>.+)', 'my_view_name'),
    ...
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```